# How to select same column of a table twice as two different columns seperated date wise

Tags: mysql

i have the following mysql query , but its taking approx 5 minutes to execute, how can i decrease its execution time

```
    select
    revenue_center_group.description as rc_group,
        revenue_center.description as revenue_center,
        count(ytd.members) as total_ytd_members,
        count(lytd.members) as total_lytd_members
    from revenue_center
    left join revenue_center_group on revenue_center_group.id = revenue_center.revenue_center_group_id
    left join (
        select membership.id as members,
            membership.rc_id as rc_id
    from membership
    where membership.status =1 
    and DATE(membership.join_date)>= (SELECT DATE_FORMAT((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date(now()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d')) ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:00'))
    and DATE(membership.join_date)<= (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(date(now()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))ytd on revenue_center.id = ytd.rc_id 
    left join (
        select
            membership.id as members,
            membership.rc_id as rc_id
    from membership
    where membership.status =1 
    and DATE(membership.join_date)>= (SELECT DATE_FORMAT((SELECT DATE_FORMAT((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date(now()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d'))
  - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y-%m-%d')) ,'%Y-01-01 00:00:00'))
and DATE(membership.join_date)<= (SELECT DATE_FORMAT((select DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(date(now()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d')
- INTERVAL 1 YEAR),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))lytd on revenue_center.id = lytd.rc_id 
    group by revenue_center_group.description,revenue_center.description with rollup;
```

Comment: the last two left join are the same ?

Comment: no the date range is different